# Oracle SQL - Import data from non-partitioned (regular table) into an empty partitioned table using expdp/impdp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle version - 12.2.0.1
OS version - 7.1 Exadata box.

I have a table with 5 million rows into a regular table (non-partitioned) and my client has created an empty structure of the above table (partitioned by date). Now, he wants to export(expdp) the data from original table (non-partitioned) and import (impdp) into the partitioned table and wants the data to go into the partitions accordingly. Is this achievable ?

Please let me know if this is achievable through any method ?

Thank you,

Comment: Is this a one time task where you want to convert a non partitioned  table to a partitioned  table then in versions after 12C you can use ALTER TABLE, check this link for more information https://sqlmaria.com/2017/05/16/extremely-useful-partitioning-enhancements-in-oracle-database-12c/

Answer (score 0):

A normal datapump with TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND will take care of it assuming the table has already been created in the target schema.

If you have a table that is *already* loaded and is unpartitioned, there is the 'alter table' option as mentioned, which lets you define the partitionined schema for both table and indexes, and do it online

```
SQL> alter table T modify
  2  partition by range (object_id) interval (10000)
  3  (
  4    partition p1 values less than (20000)
  5  ) online
  6  update indexes
  7  ( ix  local,
  8    ix2 global partition by range (created)
  9    (
 10      partition ix2_p1 values less than (date '2016-08-01'),
 11      partition ix2_p2 values less than (maxvalue)
 12    )
 13  );

Table altered.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused, you use the tag oracle10g, but mention 12.2 in the question?

Yes, this will work, on two conditions:

1. It is clear into which partition each row will be sorted. Unless you use system partitioning (`PARTITION BY SYSTEM`), that should be fine.
2. All the necessary partitions do exist. Either your client uses interval partitions (for instance `PARTITION BY RANGE (my_date) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))`), or they set up partitions to cover all dates in the unpartitioned table.